# How can I pass JSON data to a webhook Chainlink job?

Tags: chainlink

I am trying to get the "Pipeline Input" to somehow be passed to an external adapter via the `$(jobRun.requestBody)` pipeline variable and then parsed by a `jsonparse` task and then sent via a `fetch` task. I am not sure what format the input should be in when running a webhook job on a Chainlink node. I keep getting this and other errors no matter what I try:

```
data: key requestBody (segment 1 in keypath jobRun.requestBody): keypath not found
```

This is what I am seeing on the Chainlink Admin UI:
[image]

Here is the closest thing I have found in the documentation:
- https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-nodes/oracle-jobs/job-types/webhook

Here is the job definition if useful:

```ini
type = "webhook"
schemaVersion = 1
name = "account-balance-webhook"
forwardingAllowed = false
observationSource = """
parse_request  [type="jsonparse" path="data,address" data="$(jobRun.requestBody)"]
fetch        [type=bridge name="test" requestData="{\\"id\\": \\"0\\", \\"data\\": { \\"address\\": \\"$(parse_request)\\"}}"]
parse        [type=jsonparse path="data,free" data="$(fetch)"]

    parse_request -> fetch -> parse
"""
```

I am running Chainlink in a Docker container with this image: smartcontract/chainlink:1.11.0-root

**Some background**: I am working on developing an external adapter and want to be able to easily and quickly test.

Answer (score 0):

We use the following [webhook](https://github.com/Block-Farms/Chainlink-Job-Spec-Template-Smart-Contract-Archive/tree/main/1_Webhook) job to quickly verify there is no syntax errors, etc. with the bridge to an EA.

```
type            = "webhook"
schemaVersion   = 1
name = "[WH-username] cbor0-v0"
observationSource   = """
    fetch [type="bridge" name="bridge_name" requestData="{ \\"id\\": $(jobSpec.externalJobID), \\"input1\\": \\"value1\\" }"]
    parse [type=jsonparse path="data,results" data="$(fetch)"]

    fetch -> parse
"""
```

In general, its best to quickly test an EA directly through `curl GET/POST`. If the `curl` works, then a bridge will work as long as you named the bridge correctly in the `job-spec.toml`

Comment: This is more of a work-around. This doesn't explain how the "Pipeline Input" field works. This requires a new job to be created each time I want to test new input. Ideally, I would be able to enter new input in this field (in the screenshot). I appreciate your response!

Comment: Its not going to be faster in general, if you are bench testing the EA and various inputs with a webhook. You should test with curl GET/POST.

Comment: Right, testing the EA directly would be quicker. My question has more to do with what it the proper way of passing data to the web hook Chainlink job at this point. Basically, what how do I get this "Pipeline Input" textarea to work.

Comment: My answer contains the option to pass inputs into the EA request with requestData, just add whichever variables and their keys to requestData. It will only return static variables, or I am not sure what you originally meant with new inputs. Each new input will require you to change the job-spec.toml. Which is why I suggested just testing the EA directly as editing the job-spec.toml constantly would be unnecessary.